# Azure Relay - Not able to Consume/Receive events via Azure Hybrid Connection with Node

Tags: azure-eventgrid, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-servicebusrelay

We are working on integration where we have to consume/receive the events by initiating hybrid connection to Azure relay. we are able to do the successful connection using [hyco-ws](https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay-node/tree/master/hyco-ws) npm package but we are not receiving any events.

As per [hybrid connection protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol), service will send 'accept' notification to the listener to establish new control channel for all subsequent interactions.

From where can we trigger 'accept' notification so listener can receive events from the Azure relay?

We are following [Azure Relay Hybrid Connections WebSocket NodeJs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-node-get-started) to setup the listener.

[image]

Are we on right direction to receive the events via hybrid connection?

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to consuming and receiving events, Run the code to send messages since the message sent will be displayed on the listening Output. The message is sent when the listener is active.

- Create an Azure Relay Hybrid Connections from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-node-get-started#create-a-namespace).

[image]

- The code below creates a WebSocket client that connects to the Azure Service Bus Relay using the `hyco-ws` library and sends messages to the Azure Service Bus Relay using a WebSocket connection. Code reference form [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-node-get-started#write-some-code-to-send-messages)

**Code:**

```java
const WebSocket = require('hyco-ws');
const readline = require('readline')
    .createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });;

  
WebSocket.relayedConnect(
    WebSocket.createRelaySendUri(ns, path),
    WebSocket.createRelayToken('http://'+ns, keyrule, key),
    function (wss) {
        readline.on('line', (input) => {
            wss.send(input, null);
        });

        console.log('Started client interval.');
        wss.on('close', function () {
            console.log('stopping client interval');
            process.exit();
        });
    }
);
```

**Output:**

**Sending message**

[image]

**Listening**
[image]

Comment: Got a 401 error while sending events because the shared access policy only allows listening, not sending. In our case, the event sender is the third party and they only allow listening.

Comment: check the valid access